# sort the json array in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, sorting

```
create table sort(authorized json);
insert into sort values('{"name":"Authorized","states":[{"state_code":"CT","state_name":"Connecticut","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"NJ","state_name":"New Jersey","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"SC","state_name":"South Carolina","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"FL","state_name":"Florida","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"MT","state_name":"Montana","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"GA","state_name":"Georgia","is_checked":false},
{"state_code":"IA","state_name":"Iowa","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"AR","state_name":"Arkansas","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"UT","state_name":"Utah","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"ID","state_name":"Idaho","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"IL","state_name":"Illinois","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"IN","state_name":"Indiana","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"MA","state_name":"Massachusetts","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"MI","state_name":"Michigan","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"MS","state_name":"Mississippi","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"NM","state_name":"New Mexico","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"NV","state_name":"Nevada","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"RI","state_name":"Rhode Island","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"SD","state_name":"South Dakota","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"UT","state_name":"Utah","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"WV","state_name":"West Virginia","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"SD","state_name":"South Dakota","is_checked":false},
{"state_code":"WV","state_name":"West Virginia","is_checked":false}]}')
```

I want that this json sort according to `state_code` after update it looks like

```
{"name":"Authorized","states":[{"state_code":"AR","state_name":"Arkansas","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"CT","state_name":"Connecticut","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"FL","state_name":"Florida","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"GA","state_name":"Georgia","is_checked":false},
{"state_code":"IA","state_name":"Iowa","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"ID","state_name":"Idaho","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"IL","state_name":"Illinois","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"IN","state_name":"Indiana","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"MA","state_name":"Massachusetts","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"MI","state_name":"Michigan","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"MS","state_name":"Mississippi","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"MT","state_name":"Montana","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"NJ","state_name":"New Jersey","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"NM","state_name":"New Mexico","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"NV","state_name":"Nevada","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"RI","state_name":"Rhode Island","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"SC","state_name":"South Carolina","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"SD","state_name":"South Dakota","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"UT","state_name":"Utah","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"WV","state_name":"West Virginia","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"SD","state_name":"South Dakota","is_checked":false},{"state_code":"UT","state_name":"Utah","is_checked":false},
{"state_code":"WV","state_name":"West Virginia","is_checked":false}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select substr(column_name, position ('state_code":"' in column_name)+13,4) as stateCode
from table_name
order by stateCode asc/desc
```

*note:the value **13** represents the lenght of field (state_code":) and **4** represents value of field ("AR")*

might need to tweak a little according to you table and column. The select part would select your desired element then you only have to order it by asc or desc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results ordered when retrieving the data through sorting within the subquery while extracting the concerned array(`states`) as a seperate column, and then aggregating the individual objects of the array back while adhering `name` element of the object such as

```
SELECT JSON_AGG(
                JSON_BUILD_OBJECT( 'name', name, 'states', states)
               ) AS authorized 
  FROM
  (
   SELECT authorized->'name' AS name, j.states
     FROM sort,
          JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(authorized->'states') AS j(states)
    ORDER BY j.states->>'state_code' ) AS ns
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4853b40767079bd063e15a7f9b9eb96e)</kbd>